# What materials have LEGO Bricks been made from?

Tags: connections

Inspired by [this comment](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/18070/how-heavy-is-the-lego-gold-brick#comment23657_18073), I wonder, what materials have LEGO Bricks been made out of, apart from plastic? Can these also interlock with other blocks?

###### **Please Note**: I am only asking about *bricks*, and thusly not any components such as motors.

Comment: By "bricks", do you actually mean just bricks ? Or any lego parts that are not motors ? Ie. does the rubber used in tyres, rubber bands, etc. count ? Or the cloth used in various capes etc. ? How about the different types of plastic that are used (sometimes in one part) ?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker the question is just asking for bricks, so tyres and rubber bands would not be included...

Comment: So you're just interested in the (typically) rectangular 1 stud high parts with studs on top ? None of the following would match that definition ? Something like [this](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3137c01) (which has a metal axle) ? Or something like [this](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=61406pb06) (different materials in the same mould) ? Or [this](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4757) (studs with metal contacts) or even [this](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4771) (with lights) ?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker for these examples, I would allow the first, third and fourth options but only if we are talking about the brick itself, i.e. not talking about the axles, metal contacts or LED components. Basically, what the actual LEGO brick shape is made of if that makes sense. I'll allow any 'traditional' LEGO bricks including plates...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignoring the different kinds of plastic that LEGO have used for their bricks over the years (formerly CA, HIPS, Bakelite, PC - currently (M)ABS - and a range of different plastic types for parts that need different properties), I can't think of any bricks that came with LEGO sets that fit your criteria.

If we expand the scope to the gear category (things like key chains, clothing, storage solutions, etc. with the LEGO brand), there are a few that seem to fit your criteria. The ones I can think of :

- [14 Karat Gold Brick](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?G=goldbrick) made of 14-karat gold

[image]

- [2 x 4 Brick - Sterling Silver (925) Key Chain](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?G=KC126) made of Sterling silver 925

[image]

- [Eraser, 2 x 4 Brick with 3 Holes on Bottom](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?G=eraser01) - unsure what it's made of - likely some synthetic rubber or gum (which you might label as "plastic", in which case it doesn't match your criteria)

[image]

I have none of these, so can't attest to their ability to interlock with regular bricks, nor to their clutch power. I also haven't been able to find information on this (the former two are very rare).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for - thanks so much!

Comment: I had the eraser bricks, and they do indeed work with regular Lego elements! (I'd imagine not very repeatedly though, as they will of course wear quite badly).

Answer (score 2):

As noted in [this related question](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/123/what-is-inside-the-weight-element-brick), part [73020b "2x6x2 weighted brick"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=73090b) contains a chunk of (what seems to be) galvanized iron.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer - this is partly what I'm looking for. Mainly, I'm asking for which bricks have the outer brick made from another material, and a list of these, but still +1 for the answer :)